# Choosing the right Active Directory solution for my network

Tags: active-directory, vpn, windows-server-2016, entra-id

I currently manage my users "manually" on a network that began with 3 people and 3 computers. Now I have 4 users with their own computer, 4 computers used by parttime people and a second site in another building where we provide courses, so I have 10 computers for the students and 1 for the professor.

There is 1 Synology NAS by site to store the datas.

while the network was growing, I had other priorities than adapting it and now, I can finally take time.

I want to put an active directory so I can manage the users with their access to the NAS and I am a little stuck in my research because the last time I did this, was in 2010 and on an old microsoft server.

Now that we have Microsoft Azure, Office 365 (that we are using), DSM, I am not sure if I can manage everything with a distant Active Directory, throught VPNs so all my sites are on the same network. Or should I build a server and put on the last Windows Server and a VPN between my 2 sites ?

Comment: Define "everything". Do you want just a directory with LDAP auth? Are you managing assets in Azure? Do you have a device management tool (MDM) already? Do you want to use full Group Policy for more control of devices?

Comment: By "Everything" I mean the computers, the printers and the Synology. I have no MDM. A full group policy can be a good thing for the future of the network.

Sorry if I miss some informations !